# Example of QuasR failed to run

Tags: r, bioconductor

In QuasR package of R Bioconductor, it was reported that:

> Error in get(name, envir = asNamespace(pkg), inherits = FALSE) : 
>     object 'finalize_filexp' not found" when running the "example(qCount)".

This issue appeared after I updated the 'XVector' and ‘GenomicAlignments' to the latest version. How do I resolve that problem?

It was running well when the 'XVector' verison was 0.20 and ‘GenomicAlignments' version was 0.16

```
> example(qCount)

qCount> library(GenomicRanges)

qCount> library(Biostrings)

qCount> library(Rsamtools)

qCount> # copy example data to current working directory
qCount> file.copy(system.file(package="QuasR", "extdata"), ".",       recursive=TRUE)
[1] TRUE

qCount> # load genome sequence
qCount> genomeFile <- "extdata/hg19sub.fa"

qCount> gseq <- readDNAStringSet(genomeFile)

Error in get(name, envir = asNamespace(pkg), inherits = FALSE) : 
object 'finalize_filexp' not found
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved by updating the Biostrings and Rsamtools.